# CMake: file(STRINGS) parsing confusing newlines

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I am working on a project, and in the compilation system I need to read each line of the CONFIG file to generate a header file config.h.
When using `file(STRINGS)` in CMake to obtain the string content of each line, when the string contains`]`,`[`,`;`, the obtained content will not be as expected.

a part of CONFIG file:

```
CONFIG_FEAT_A=y
CONFIG_FEAT_B=y
CONFIG_SOME_CHARS=" ,.;:-_)]}"
CONFIG_SIZE=0
```

a part of CMakeList.txt:

```
file(STRINGS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/.config ConfigContents)
foreach(NameAndValue ${ConfigContents})
  string(REGEX REPLACE "^[ ]+" "" NameAndValue ${NameAndValue})
  string(REGEX MATCH "^CONFIG[^=]+" NAME ${NameAndValue})
  string(REPLACE "${NAME}=" "" VALUE ${NameAndValue})
  if(NAME AND NOT "${VALUE}" STREQUAL "")
    if(${VALUE} STREQUAL "y")
      file(APPEND ${CONFIG_H} "#define ${NAME} 1\n")
    elseif(${VALUE} STREQUAL "m")
      file(APPEND ${CONFIG_H} "#define ${NAME} 2\n")
    elseif(${VALUE} STREQUAL "n")
      file(APPEND ${CONFIG_H} "#undef ${NAME}\n")
    else()
      if(NOT "${VALUE}" STREQUAL "")
        file(APPEND ${CONFIG_H} "#define ${NAME} ${VALUE}\n")
      endif()
    endif()
  endif()
endforeach()
```

**The first two lines can be parsed correctly**

```
#define CONFIG_FEAT_A 1
#define CONFIG_FEAT_B 1
```

**But the parsing of the third line is very strange. First, it discards the `;` character and merges it with the fourth line.**

```
#define CONFIG_SOME_CHARS " ,.:-_)]}";CONFIG_SIZE=0
```

What is the problem and how can I get the correct result?
Many thanks

I tried removing the `]` in the configuration `,.;:-_)]}` and that seemed to get the line breaks correct. But it will still be lost `;`

Comment: If you *suspect* that `file(STRINGS)` behaves unexpectedly, why don't verify that **immediately** by printing its result (`message("ConfigContents: ${ConfigContents}")`)? Or print the iterator in the `foreach` loop: `message(NameAndValue: ${NameAndValue}")`. Additionally applying the REGEX (and observing its results) just makes the debugging more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
As you said, I actually use message to debug in my own environment. The REGEX code is required for functionality.